# How to build an sp conditionned by the last 2 letters of a cell member?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL table like :

```
Name       Value
alex ph     0.5
max pr      0.4
jean ph     0.6
```

I want to create a stored procedure where i put as a variable the two last letter of the column's name member and it return the corresponding row like :

```
exec sp_2lett @lastL = 'ph'
```

gives

```
Name       Value
alex ph    0.5
jean ph    0.6
```

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, I would recommend that you use a table-valued function rather than a stored procedure for this.  You can then use the results in a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you can do the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_2lett
@lastL varchar(2)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE RIGHT(Name,2) = @lastL
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [USP_Select_Names](@Name nvarchar(2))
AS
BEGIN
SELECT [Name], [Value] FROM TableName WHERE [Name] LIKE '%'+@Name
END
```

Comment: It is not good. If he would have a user like 'pheby pr' it would return it.

Comment: What about `SELECT [Name], [Value] FROM TableName WHERE [Name] LIKE '%'+@Name`?